# Contact 3-manifolds with hyperkahler Stein fillings?

Tags: sg.symplectic-geometry, contact-geometry, holomorphic-symplectic, stein-manifolds, hyperkaehler

Is there any classification result on (homeomorphism type) of contact 3-manifolds $\Sigma$ that have Stein filling $W$ that is 
1. Hyperkahler (s.t. Stein structure is the Kahler part of it)
 
2. not subcritical (=its skeleton is Lagrangian).

Known examples to me are $\mathbb{S}^3/\Gamma,$ where $\Gamma\leq SU(2)$ is a finite subgroup. These manifolds are boundaries of plumbings of disc cotangent bundles $D^*\mathbb{S}^2$ according to an ADE Dynkin graph.
In particular, can $S^1\times S^2$ be such a manifold, and if not, why?

Comment: $S^1 \times S^2$ has a unique filling (up to deformation and blow-up) by $D^2 \times A$ where $A$ is the annulus. (In particular, it's subcritical.)

Comment: Can you please explain that filling, I am not sure how to see it?

Comment: What would constitute seeing it? Here's one way: think of $S^1 \times S^2$ as having an $S^1$-invariant contact structure. The $S^1$ fibres are tangent to the contact structure along the equator of $S^2$. From this, you can see that the contact structure is supported by an open book with annulus pages and a trivial monodromy. This point of view immediately gives you the filling I described. The uniqueness result follows from McDuff's paper on ruled 4 manifolds (and is probably stated there), though there are many proofs now in the literature.